# Can`t draw in CAlayer

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

HI All.

I have subclass of UIScrollView. IN this class I have added some `imageView.layer` to `self.layer`. And when I call `[imageView.layer setNeedsDisplay]` my implemented delegate never called.

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer :(CGContextRef)context
```

I`ve also set

```
imageView.layer.delegate = self
```

Could anyone tell me where I must set delegate function to make this to work.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things a little bit odd with you approach.

If ou have a ScrollView and an ImageView you don't need to add the layers, you can just do
`[scrollView addSubview: imageView];`

Also, you don't need a delegate for drawing a `UIView` into a `UIWindow`.
If, however, you want to add a delegate still you can do this:
`imageView.delegate =`
A ImageView should not be his own delegate, you will need some ViewController, better a ScrollViewController.

Comment: I want to say that my problem is solved particularly. I define another class and added to this class only one function drawLayer :inContect function and set object of this class to my layer delegate. At the beggining this function is called but when i call
[myLayer setNeedsDisplay] function this function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

1. The method name is `-drawLayer:inContext:`. The delegate's method signature should be like this:

   ```
   //                                  vvvvvvvvv
   - (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer  inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
   ```
2. Don't override the delegate of another layer attached to a view (which *is* that view). This will make the view cannot operate normally.